# Count of messages in mailbox using Outlook REST API

Tags: outlook-restapi

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages?$count=true seems to return wrong value. Though I have only 31 messages in the mailbox, it gives count as 201. Has anyone been able to get the correct count of messages using the above API?

Also, Is there any other Outlook REST API that can be used to get the count of messages in the outlook mailbox?

Answer (score 3):

Querying `/me/messages?$count=true` will return the total across all folders in your mailbox. When you say only 31 messages, do you mean in the Inbox, or across all of your folders?

Comment: I mean 31 messages across all of my folders